# Pancake Sorting with a Twist (Java)

Tags: java, string, algorithm, sorting

I am attempting to solve a version of a pancake sorting algorithm. In this problem I am given a string that is composed of any combination of characters A-F and has a maximum length of 6. For instance I may receive the String 'ACFE'. In this problem I am trying to use pancake sorting to fix the string to be in Alphabetical Order. So the above example would become 'ACEF'.

That is pretty simple and straightforward. Here is the catch: the characters in the input string can be Uppercase OR Lowercase. Whenever you flip characters in the string, the flipped characters switch case. So an uppercase A would become 'a'. The goal at the end is to flip the string into order and also have all of the characters in uppercase as well.

I have had no problem putting together the algorithm to solve the sorting part of the algorithm, but it is the part where I am trying to make sure that we aren't done flipping the characters until they are all uppercase that I am having trouble with and can't seem to solve.

To make things easier on myself, I have made a HashMap of Characters to Integers so that it is easier to sort the characters (we can just use an equivalent Integer value). I also break the string apart at the beginning into a char[] and put it in reverse order to make the algorithm easier for myself.

Here is the code I use to do everything:

```
private static final HashMap<Character, Integer> numericalEquivalent = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        numericalEquivalent.put('A', 6);
        numericalEquivalent.put('B', 5);
        numericalEquivalent.put('C', 4);
        numericalEquivalent.put('D', 3);
        numericalEquivalent.put('E', 2);
        numericalEquivalent.put('F', 1);
        numericalEquivalent.put('a', 6);
        numericalEquivalent.put('b', 5);
        numericalEquivalent.put('c', 4);
        numericalEquivalent.put('d', 3);
        numericalEquivalent.put('e', 2);
        numericalEquivalent.put('f', 1);
    }

    private static int flip(char[] arr, int i, int numFlips) {

        char temp;
        int start = 0;
        if (start < i) {
            while (start < i) {
                temp = (Character.isUpperCase(arr[start]) ? Character.toLowerCase(arr[start]) : Character.toUpperCase(arr[start]));
                arr[start] = (Character.isUpperCase(arr[i]) ? Character.toLowerCase(arr[i]) : Character.toUpperCase(arr[i]));
                arr[i] = temp;
                start++;
                i--;
            }
            numFlips++;
        }

        return numFlips;
    }

    private static int findMax(char[] arr, int n) {

        int mi, i;
        for (mi = 0, i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            if (numericalEquivalent.get(arr[i]) > numericalEquivalent.get(arr[mi]))
                mi = i;
        return mi;
    }

    private static int getFlips (char[] pancakes) {

        int n = pancakes.length;
        int numFlips = 0;

        for (int curr_size = n; curr_size > 1; --curr_size) {

            int mi = findMax(pancakes, curr_size);
            if (mi != curr_size - 1) {
                numFlips = flip(pancakes, mi, numFlips);
                if (!isSorted(pancakes))
                    numFlips = flip(pancakes, curr_size - 1, numFlips);
            }
        }
        
        return numFlips;
    }


private static boolean isSorted(char[] arr) {

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (numericalEquivalent.get(arr[i]) > numericalEquivalent.get(arr[i + 1]))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {

        while(true) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if (input.equals("0")) break;
            else System.out.println(getFlips(new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString().toCharArray()));
        }
    }
```

My goal is to get back the minimum number of flips that it will take to flip the characters into order. How can I modify this code, though, to make sure it accounts for characters being lowercase and the need to make sure they all end up in Uppercase?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the stop condition from `if (!isSorted(pancakes))` to `if (!isSortedAndUppercase(pancakes))` where `isSortedAndUppercase(pancakes)` is defined as:

```
    private static boolean isSortedAndUppercase(char[] arr){    
        return isUpperCase(arr) && isSorted(arr);
    }

    private static boolean isUpperCase(char[] arr) {
        String s = String.valueOf(arr);
        return s.equals(s.toUpperCase());
    }
```

and stop the search only when the stop condition is met.
Consider using Breadth-First Search for this task.

Side notes:

There is no need to map chars into integers. Try the following:

```
    char[] chars =   "ABCDEF".toCharArray();

     for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
         System.out.println(chars[i] +" int value: "+(int)chars[i]);
         System.out.println(Character.toLowerCase(chars[i]) +" int value: "+(int)Character.toLowerCase(chars[i]));
     }
```